# VBA to find the folder the workbook is saved in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of code to pick out all xlsx files in a folder and place them into one workbook. I was wondering if I could get the vba to find the folder the master work book is saved in or if the vba could ask which folder I want to select.

```
Sub GetSheets()

    Path = "S:\xxxxx\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you create an xlxm workbook, create a module and add your code then amend `Path = S:\xxxxx` to the required value, does this code do what you want? For example, do you mind the sequence of worksheets being reversed? Do you mind having to create a new xlxm workbook for each folder? If you do not mind, Bishonen_PL’s answer is probably correct if unclear. `Path = ThisWorkbook.Path` sets Path to the name of the folder containing the workbook. When you tried this change, did you put the xlxm workbook in the folder containing the source workbooks?

Answer (score 2):

```
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please add an explanation for your code.

Comment: unfortunately I have tried this just now and it doesn't work it runs through but doesn't pick up any worksheets, the code I put does the same is you don't include the \ after the file path, is there anyway to add this?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer This:

```
        Sub openfldr()

        Dim fldr As FileDialog
        Dim sItem As String
        Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select a Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
NextCode:
        GetFolder = sItem
        Set fldr = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately I have tried this just now and it doesn't work it runs through but doesn't pick up any worksheets, the code I put does the same is you don't include the \ after the file path, is there anyway to add this?